# Sorting an object array based on a property

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

EDIT: Added some information.

I got an array of Objects. Each object has a name and a value. I need to sort the objects in descending order of those values, and print the names. I saw this easy solution but can't seem to apply it to my problem: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

The code compiles with no error but the array is not sorted **at all**. I know this because I know what the output should be i.e. the output should be something like var364, var200, var65 etc. and what i get is var1, var2, var3 etc.

I tried to strip the code of the irrelevant parts here:

Main class

```
print(data.preselection());

private void print (UnitRow preselectedUnitRow) {
    out.printf("Variables after preselection: \n");
    for (int i=0;i<PRESELECTION_LIMIT;i++) {
        out.printf("%s, ",preselectedUnitRow.getUnitName(i));
    }
}
```

Dataset (data)

```
private UnitRow data;

...

public UnitRow preselection() {
    UnitRow standardDeviationUnits = new UnitRow(numberOfVariables);
    for (int i=0;i<numberOfVariables;i++){
        Unit unit = new Unit(1,variableNames[i],calculateStandardDeviation(i));
        standardDeviationUnits.add(unit);
    }
    standardDeviationUnits.sort();
    return standardDeviationUnits;
}
```

UnitRow

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UnitRow {

    private Unit[] units;
    private int count;

    ...

    public void sort() {
        Arrays.sort(units);
    }
}
```

Unit

```
public class Unit implements Comparable<Unit>{

    private NumberRow elements; //just a class with an array of doubles
    private String name;

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Unit compareUnit) { //getValue returns a single type double number
        int comparison = (int) (compareUnit.getValue(0) - getValue(0));
        return comparison;
    }
}
```

I am assuming my implementation of Comparable is wrong. Can you spot the problem?
I say this because I tested as following:

```
System.out.println(standardDeviationUnits.getValue(0,0));
standardDeviationUnits.sort();
System.out.println(standardDeviationUnits.getValue(0,0));
```

And the exact same value is returned.

Comment: Why do you think that your `compareTo` is wrong? Do you get a compile-time error, or does the array not sort correctly?

Comment: Yes forgot to mention. The code compiles with no error, yet the array is not sorted (at all). it seems as if the sort is not even called. I know it is not sorted since I know what the output should look like.

Comment: Why not, in the unit compareTo, just do return getValue(0) - CompareUnit.getValue(0)?

Comment: Put a `system.out.println()` inside compareTo to see if it is called

Comment: What object / data type is returned by `getValue`? Is it from the array of doubles?

Comment: @JakeArnold I tried that too, same result.

Comment: @smttsp Did that, it seems to be called the same number of times as the number of Units in UnitRow.

Comment: @user184994 It returns a double.

Comment: Does this make any sense? UnitRow preselectedUnitRow = new UnitRow(data.getNumberOfVariables());
preselectedUnitRow = data.preselection();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like reverse order

```
public int compareTo(Unit compareUnit) {
    if (getValue(0) < compareUnit.getValue(0)) return 1;
    else if (getValue(0) > compareUnit.getValue(0)) return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Try this.

Also note that in your `compareTo`, you unnecessarily wrote return 2; and wrote 3 `if` instead of 1 `if-else`.

Comment: Hmm tried my original code but with if-else statements. Doesn't work. Then also tried your code and still the same result. I'll update the main questions because I seem to have found a rather different problem in the code. I'll respond soon.

Comment: This worked! I admit, had another mistake that was ruining everything, but your solution is the one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sort as per names:

```
return compareUnit.name.compareTo(name);
```

else I have no idea what attribute your getValue(0) returns to you but still if you are trying to sort as per getValue(0):

```
return compareUnit.getValue(0)-getValue(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please check the main post again, I added how I tested and noticed that the sort doesn't work. Also added that getValue returns a single number type double. Sadly, your solution does not work. I really have no clue what's going wrong.